# Ionic framework and angularjs imgcache not working on iOS device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, caching, hybrid-mobile-app

I have built a hybrid app with ionic framework.
I have used angular imgcache (https://github.com/jBenes/angular-imgcache.js/tree/master) to allow caching of images fetched from an external site.

I am using code such as:

```
<img img-cache ic-src="{{src}}"/>
```

It works a treat in browser (after using 'ionic serve') on command line.
I have tested it in ionic view iOS app.
I have now take the xcodeproj that it creates and distributed it for testing but the images do not load.

I have even added the cordova whitelist plugin and set metas to allow CORS requests.

Does anybody have any other ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: same issue here. Works in the browser but not on a device (however I am currently using ionicView which could be the cause). I followed the doc and made sure I $init() the cache when the platform is ready

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you set the img cache to manual init `ImgCacheProvider.manualInit = true;`in your `app.config` function.

Second step - call `ImgCache.$init()` anytime after deviceready event (in your case, somewhere in the `$ionicPlatform.ready` function).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not accessing an HTTPS endpoint, you might benefit from checking that your App Transport Security settings in the .plist file (found in platforms/ios/{app_name}/{app_name}-Info.plist)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs$
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    ...
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

From this resource: [Publishing an Ionic Angular App for iOS - The Hidden Steps & Pitfalls](http://www.righthandedmonkey.com/2016/01/publishing-ionic-angular-app-for-ios.html) .